# Inaccurate measurement double load cell circuit

Tags: arduino, load-cell

I’m building a circuit with two load cells and I have some issues getting accurate measurements. At first I just soldered the load cells onto the load cell amplifier but as the connections seemed bad I added a wire to board terminal block to have a « cleaner » connection but that doesn’t seem to have changed anything. I built a custom PCB for the whole circuit as there is also a battery, on/off switch and an arduino. This is my first project, I’m fairly new to electronics. Please tell me if there is something I’m doing wrongly.

Schematic: [image: board schematic]

Board: [image: board]

Assembled device: [image: Assembled device top] [image: Assembled device top closeup] [image: assembled device bottom]

This is the code I ran to get the measurements:

```
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>
#include <HX711_ADC.h>
​
BLEService OneRM ("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
BLEFloatCharacteristic OneRMCharacteristic("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", BLERead | BLENotify);
​
const int HX711_dout = 3;
const int HX711_sck = 2;
​
HX711_ADC LoadCell(HX711_dout, HX711_sck);
​
unsigned long t = 0;
​
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  delay (10);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Starting...");
​
  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("BLE Startup Failed.");
    while (1);
  } else {
    Serial.println("BLE Startup Worked.");
  }
​
  BLE.setLocalName("OneRM");
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(OneRM);
  OneRM.addCharacteristic(OneRMCharacteristic);
  BLE.addService(OneRM);
​
  BLE.advertise();
  Serial.println("Bluetooth device active, waiting for connections...");
​
  LoadCell.begin();
  float calibrationValue;
  calibrationValue = -50;
​
  unsigned long stabilizingtime = 2000;
  boolean _tare = true;
  LoadCell.start(stabilizingtime, _tare);
  if (LoadCell.getTareTimeoutFlag()) {
    Serial.println("Timeout, check MCU>HX711 wiring and pin designations");
    while (1);
  } else {
    LoadCell.setCalFactor(calibrationValue);
    Serial.println("Startup is complete");
  }
}
​
void loop() {
​
  static boolean newDataReady = 0;
  const int serialPrintInterval = 0;
​
  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();
​
  if (central) {
    Serial.print("Connected to central: ");
    Serial.println(central.address());
    while (central.connected()) {
      if (LoadCell.update()) newDataReady = true;
      if (newDataReady) {
        if (millis() > t + serialPrintInterval) {
          float i = LoadCell.getData();
          Serial.print("Load_cell output val: ");
          Serial.println(i);
          OneRMCharacteristic.writeValue(i);
          newDataReady = 0;
          t = millis();
        }
      }
​
      if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char inByte = Serial.read();
        if (inByte == 't') LoadCell.tare();
      }
​
      if (LoadCell.getTareStatus() == true) {
        Serial.println("Tare complete");
      }
    }
​
    Serial.print(F("Disconnected from central: "));
    Serial.println(central.address());
  }
}
```

Comment: How have you determined that the measurements are not accurate?

Comment: Connected to my computer, ran a load cell measuring program. And I then get random numbers that don’t really make sense when I interact with the sensors. I know sensors are accurate to about ~5% but the measurements are really completely wrong.

Comment: What's a "load cell measuring program"? Is it sample code for your Nano? Are you using the HX711 library that Sparkfun provides? Can you edit your post to include the code?

Comment: How did you get your calibration factor? What's your expected data, and what are you actually receiving?

Comment: I tried to adapt the calibration factor by placing known weights on the scale: 0kg, 1kg, 5kg, 10kg. But the data I receive is completely off it’s not increasing / decreasing proportionally with the placed weights. It can go up then go down without any real reason. Even when there is no weight the data i’m retrieving is still varying.

Comment: I notice your load cell wires aren't standard colours. What load cell are you using? Also -- I'm assuming your board layout image is upside down relative to the way your hand is holding the physical device (in the picture with the monitor)?

Comment: This is the link of the load cells i’m currently using: [load cell](https://www.amazon.com.be/dp/B07HBP1167?ref_=cm_sw_r_apin_dp_4QAGDBA57TTR68T34HBF). Yes I’m indeed holding the sensor upside down compared to the board layout.

Comment: @tomcajot - A normal load-cell have four wires and you have connected six wires. You have there red/red/white/black/black/white. But it should be red/red/black/black/white/green. If you use red and black for the voltage source, this would be okay and good to understand. Then two white wires for the output voltage? So how you did it right now, this is a bit confusing.

Comment: To wire them up I just followed these guides: [sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide/all), [double load cell](https://circuitjournal.com/img/articles/10_50kg_load_cell/HX711_2x50kg_load_cell_diagram.webp?v=19)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention there are two load cells.

Comment: Those aren't load cells but are load sensors. They don't provide a differential signal for the ADC. Did you follow the instructions for using four load sensors + the Combinator Board in your Sparkfun link?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it with the answer you posted! Is the second link (double load cell) I posted above wrong then?

Comment: Not sure -- it's asking me to download a .webp file onto my phone and I'm unfamiliar with the extension. If it's for two *load cells*, though, it's likely the wrong one for you.

Comment: My bad, here’s the [link](https://circuitjournal.com/50kg-load-cells-with-HX711)

Comment: Wrote a huge answer and after all that I realized I had the wire colours messed up. Sorry -- you've already got your system wired right, I think. (WBBWRR). I notice your purple board has mirror symmetry. Is it possible you soldered it upside-down?

Comment: I’ll try to move the wires from left to right to right to left, although I doubt I soldered them on the wrong side. I’ll look into it and come back to you. Thx!

Comment: It seems that the main issue is that both load sensors weren't being pressed at the same time, I'll try to build a mechanical fixture for that and check the results I get back. Thank you for you time.